# log4j2 not workig properly, creating 2 files with same name. The compressed one is currupted

Tags: java, xml, compression, log4j2

I am using `SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy` and `TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy` both with Log4j2 for my app with following XML:

```xml
        <RollingRandomAccessFile name="app_log" fileName="logs/app.log"
                                 filePattern="logs/app-%d{yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm':00Z'}.%i.log.gz">
            <PatternLayout>
                <Pattern>%d %p %c{1.} [%t] [%X{opc-request-id}] %replace{%m}{[\n\r]+}{} %ex{full}{separator( | )}%n</Pattern>
            </PatternLayout>
            <Policies>
                <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy interval="60" modulate="true"/>
                <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="250 MB"/>
            </Policies>
            <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="20">
                <Delete basePath="logs/" followLinks="True">
                    <IfFileName glob="app-*.log*">
                        <IfAny>
                            <IfLastModified age="14d"/>
                            <IfAccumulatedFileSize exceeds="6 GB"/>
                        </IfAny>
                    </IfFileName>
                </Delete>
            </DefaultRolloverStrategy>
        </RollingRandomAccessFile>
```

But this policy is not working as expected. I can see few files with size > 251 MB. There are two copy of these types of files one is compressed and other without compression.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3twVI.png)

These type of files are very less though but they are increasing host space. Can somebody please help me understand what i am missing here. Appreciate your help in advance.

Comment: You probably ran out of space on your filesystem during the log rollover.

Comment: This issue is very intermittent, still now fileSystem utilization is 100% but now its not happening, anything i am missing.

Comment: @PiotrP.Karwasz Also, on some other node there is no such space issue.